# Best way to add "display: flex" to flexslider2 [wordpress plugin] slide?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, flexbox, flexslider

I want to add "display: flex" to flexslider2 slides but the plugin's javascript sets the slides to "display: block" so I can't just declare that in my wp theme stylesheet because the javascript's style declarations take precedence over the stylesheet's. I ***can*** go in and change the lines of code in the flexslider.js that but then I run into the trouble of having those lines overwritten when the wordpress plugin gets updated. So, what's the best way to override javascript css? Should I even be using the flexslider plugin? Is there a better way to use jquery/js to create a slider that I can use flex properties on? It seemed the cleanest and easiest slider plugin to implement as a featured posts slider in wp. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override script style by adding the `!important` after the CSS prop.
Example:

```
.flexslider2{
  display: flex !important;
}
```

Note: avoid the `!important` usage, because it can lead to unexpected CSS results.